# XElement to Dictionary with same keys alternative

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml like this

```
<parent id="001">
    <first>Brian</first>
    <last>Johnson</last>
    <gender>Male</gender>
</parent>
```

My code currently handles it as such:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> GetParentInfo(string id, XDocument xml)
{
    var parent = xml.Descendants("parent")
                    .Where(p => p.Attribute("id").Value == id)
                    .FirstOrDefault();

    var parentInfo = parent.Elements()
                           .ToDictionary(x => x.Name.LocalName, x => X.Value);

    return parentInfo;
}
```

My issue is that my xml is now changing to:

```
<parent id="001">
    <first>Brian</first>
    <last>Johnson</last>
    <gender>Male</gender>
    <child>Jimmy</child>
    <child>Janet</child>
    <child>Carl</child>
</parent>
```

Dictionary is no longer suitable and I can't think of how to handle this change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create your Parent class like this:

```
    private class Parent
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> Children { get; set; }
    }
```

And have a Factory method which parses your xml:

```
    private static Parent ParentInfo(string id, XDocument xml)
    {
        return xml.Descendants("parent")
                .Where(p => (string)p.Attribute("id") == id)
                .Select(x => new Parent {
                            FirstName = (string)x.Element("first"),
                            LastName = (string)x.Element("last"),
                            Gender = (string)x.Element("gender"),
                            Children = x.Elements("child").Select(y => (string)y)
                           })
                .FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Annoying xml schema to parse though.

---

Edit: using casts instead of calls to .Value so it is more resilient to null values.

Comment: Oh hey... this is good idea. I didn't think about that. I can actually change the xml schema too, any suggestions? I don't deal with xml a lot. Thought this would be the easiest

Comment: wrap the child elements in a `children` element or make the first, last and gender attributes of the `parent` element.

Answer (score 0):

how about writing a class for Parent, and then a constructor for it which takes in an XElement and parses it into properties on the class.  You can still keep the dictionary, but it'll be `Dictionary<string, Parent>`

```
public class Parent
{
  public string ID {get;set;}
  public string First {get;set;}
  public string Last {get;set;}
  public string Gender {get;set;}
  public List<string> ChildrensNames {get;set;}

  public Parent(XElement parentXML) { // parse XML and fill properties
  }

}
```

Comment: I already have Parent class exactly as you wrote it. My issue is that I would like to keep XElement out of the class in case in the future I change from XML to say perhaps a Database, hence why I tried to keep with something general such as a dictionary.

Comment: You could make a Factory class then which generates parents from an XElement.  Then the Parent is not associated with XElement.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I went with a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` and that seems to work with what I got.